# I need to convert my Mysql database to SQL Server 2005 database

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

I need to convert my Mysql database to SQL Server 2005 database, Is there any tools available for this conversion.

Comment: Here's a description of [how to accomplish this](http://studentclub.ro/lucians_weblog/archive/2007/04/30/migrate-from-mysql-to-ms-sql-server-2005-express-edition.aspx). I can't speak as to how safe or well this works.

Comment: literally the 2rd link down from my url... which is why I posted, the url...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest a generic, standards-based, platform-independent approach, applicable to any two databases. Taken streight from an answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689098/how-to-bulk-insert-a-csv-file-into-sqlite-c/2689229#2689229), you can use any of the following tools:

- [SQL Workbench](http://www.sql-workbench.net/), using the [WbCopy](http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/command-copy.html) command
- an [ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) tool, like [Pentaho Data Integration](http://www.pentaho.com/products/data_integration/)
- [DDLUtils](http://db.apache.org/ddlutils/)

All of these will allow you to tweak the migration process to some degree (e.g. batch size).