# Best way to Bulk Insert from a C# DataTable

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I have a `DataTable` that I want to push to the DB. I want to be able to say like

```
myDataTable.update();
```

But after reading the MSDN [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkdwwdkf(v=VS.80).aspx), apparently this does inserts row by row.

> It should be noted that these statements are not performed as a batch process; each row is updated individually.

What are my alternatives?

Edit: I am using SQL Server 2005

Comment: Your options depend on what server you are using.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If using SQL Server, `SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(DataTable)`

- [SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer Method (DataTable)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x.aspx)

Or also with SQL Server, you can write it to a .csv and use `BULK INSERT`

- [BULK INSERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)

If using MySQL, you could write it to a .csv and use `LOAD DATA INFILE`

- [LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html)

If using Oracle, [you can use the array binding feature of ODP.NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2009/09-sep/o59odpnet-085168.html)

- [Bulk Insert to Oracle using .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343299/bulk-insert-to-oracle-using-net/797636#797636)

If SQLite:

- [How do I bulk insert with SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928873/how-do-i-bulk-insert-with-sqlite)
- [Faster bulk inserts in sqlite3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364017/faster-bulk-inserts-in-sqlite3)

Comment: The link for the ODP.NET solution is broken.

Comment: What JohnB said was awesome ,here is a nice sample with explanation.
http://www.jarloo.com/c-bulk-upsert-to-sql-server-tutorial/

Answer (score 11):

```
string connectionString= ServerName + DatabaseName + SecurityType;
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection)) {
    connection.Open();
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "TableName";
    try {
        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTableName);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.Write(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Please note that the structure of the database table and the table name should be the same or it will throw an exception.

Comment: +1 for example :).  Rather than saying "the structure should be the same", how about including  SqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings  in the example

Answer (score 4):

This is going to be largely dependent on the RDBMS you're using, and whether a .NET option even exists for that RDBMS.

If you're using SQL Server, use the [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(VS.80).aspx) class.

For other database vendors, try googling for them specifically. For example a search for ".NET Bulk insert into Oracle" turned up some interesting results, including this link back to Stack Overflow: [Bulk Insert to Oracle using .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343299/bulk-insert-to-oracle-using-net).

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I do it using a DataTable.  This is a working piece of TEST code.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
    con.Open();

    // Create a table with some rows. 
    DataTable table = MakeTable();

    // Get a reference to a single row in the table. 
    DataRow[] rowArray = table.Select();

    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
    {
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.CarlosBulkTestTable";

        try
        {
            // Write the array of rows to the destination.
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(rowArray);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

    }

}//using
```

Comment: Why do you convert to DataRow[]? the SqlBulkCoopy can take the DataTable itself as a param, so this seems like a pointless step.

Answer (score 1):

SqlBulkCopy class is best for SQL server,

[Doing Bulk Upload/Insert of DataTable to a Table in SQL server in C#](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/Framework/388_Doing_Bulk_UploadInsert_of_DataTable_to_a_Table_in_SQL_server_in_C_.aspx)